# PHP: Splitting long query string across multiple lines

Tags: php, string

I've got a long string which I want to split accross multiple lines so it's easier to read. but I'm not sure what the syntax is

```
$xml = array('sXML' =>"<queryxml><entity>Ticket</entity><query><field>Status<expression op=\"$condition1\">$complete</expression></field><condition operator=\"AND\"><field>AccountID<expression op=\"equals\">$userid</expression></field></condition><condition operator=\"AND\"><condition><field>QueueID<expression op=\"NotEqual\">$routine</expression></field></condition><condition operator=\"OR\"><field>QueueID<expression op=\"NotEqual\">$recurring</expression></field></condition><condition operator=\"OR\"><field>QueueID<expression op=\"NotEqual\">$clientmanagement</expression></field></condition></condition></query></queryxml>");
```

Can someone help me out please?

Comment: do you want to format the output or your code?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

just split it into multiple strings and concatenate them, like this:

```
$xml = array('sXML' => "lorem" .
 "ipsum" .
 "dolor");
```

or use [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php):

```
$sXML = <<<XML
your text
goes here
XML;

$xml = array('sXML' => $sXML);
```

Comment: isn't there overhead in concatenation? in other languages (at least low level one) there definitely is

Answer (score 14):

If it doesn't matter if linebreaks are added, you can simply write:

```
<?php
$xml = array('sXML' => "<abc>
<def>Asdfg</def>
</abc>";
?>
```

Comment: Clearly the best answer.

Comment: wrong answer when new line break matters. it will be a new line feed betwen `<abc>` and <def>Asdfg</def>` which is other circumstances is not wanted